# Django custom field for UUID using binary column type

Tags: django, mongodb, field, uuid

Any django plugin for custom UUID Field using binary column type? (I found some using char type which could cost too much space in my project scenario.)

or more detailed, I need an example of custom Field for binary column type in Django, which I can refer to to create MongoDB ObjectId Field in traditional DB like Mysql...

Thank for any information.

Comment: For postgres: https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield/blob/master/uuidfield/fields.py

Comment: For sqlserver 2008: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067587/custom-django-binary-field-sql-server-2008

Comment: No one is for Mysql right? I have to use Mysql.... Sigh : )